# Discord bot is not coming online

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My discord bot is not coming online.
Here is my .js file

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const TOKEN = "my-token-is-here";

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "Hello Discord Bot") {
    message.channel.send("Hi There!");
  }
  {
    console.log("Bot Is Ready!");
  }
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

The error I am getting is

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

Comment: Please remove your bot's token from your code

Comment: Can you please provide your full error? With the part of the error you've provided the problem can be anything.

Comment: You've only showed a small part of the error you're getting, you should get an error which is longer. Can you please show the full error?

Comment: In future please only add tags that are relevant to your issue. `discord.net` and `discord.jda` should not be tagged here.

Answer (score 0):

You should never post any private tokens publicly. Be sure to make a new token on the Discord-Developer-Portal and don't continue using this one!

To your question:
It seems like the lines

```
{
    console.log("Bot Is Ready!");
}
```

cause the syntax error. You probably want to move that statement into it's own event handler for the event "ready" (triggered when DiscordJs has finished setting up the bot-client for you).

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "Hello Discord Bot") {
    message.channel.send("Hi There!");
  }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot Is Ready!");
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you've installed Discord.js version 13.1.0 but your NodeJS version is lower than 16.6. There are two options for you to solve this problem.

#### Option 1 (most recommended)

You'll need to update your NodeJS version to 16.6 or higher. You can do this by downloading a version of NodeJS at [the NodeJS website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and complete the setup again.

Once you've completed the setup you should be able to run your Discord bot again.

#### Option 2

If you **don't** want to update your version you can install Discord.js version 12.5.3. This version is not as stable as version 13.1.0 is but it is possible. You can do this by using the npm command `npm install discord.js@12.5.3`. After installing the 12.5.3 version you should be able to run your bot again.

---

Also like Luca Mertens noticed your breaks are incorrectely. You should replace them to

```js
client.on('ready', () => console.log(`Bot is ready`));

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "Hello Discord Bot") {
        message.channel.send("Hi There!");
    }
});
```